# How to keep the root Rails 4 app from accepting subdomains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain

When I originally wrote the API for my website, I wanted to have it as a subdomain like so: `api.example.com`. That worked. Now I am changing it so api can only work when trying to access it as part of the URLL `example.com/api/...`. Now this works except locally `api.example.com/api...` works still. More interesting is the fact that some random subdomain does not work. On the production site though any subdomain works, which is not what I want. Is there a way to ensure that subdomains aren't caught by the root in Rails 4?

As an extra question that hopefully is answered, but doesn't have to be, how can I redirect to another subdomain using the routes. I haven't been able to figure it out and I am wondering if it is possible.